# how to crop the blank part from an image (document form) in python?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbNQF.png)I have a scanned copy of a document as an image submitted by the user, it covers only 40% of the paper's height. I want to crop only that part, how to achieve this.
It is not necessary that the required form will always be on the top of the paper, it can be anywhere and the rest is blank white paper, how to crop that part?

The scanned copy I have got using scanner made in python only, so it has little black dots in the page.

Comment: Good starting point for an answer would be some testing material and your current approach

Comment: I have tried searching for similar image but could not found and I can't submit original document here so. It is just with less than half the height of a4 paper but user first got that document printed and sent that a4 paper as scanned copy, I need to crop that form only.

Comment: Can you share image sample and expected result?

Comment: I have share an image, I need the content part only, like you see 70% of portion is blank. But it won't be necessary that the content party will be on top always.

Comment: Use [threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57), so that the (more or less) white part is neglected (use `THRESH_BINARY_INV` parameter). Then, just iterate over the image looking for the minimum and maximum `x` and `y` values with value `255`. These four points describe a rectangle, where anything non-white should be present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider the steps below to crop the blank or the none blank part:

```
cv::namedWindow("result", cv::WINDOW_FREERATIO);
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(R"(xbNQF.png)"); // read the image

// main code starts from here
cv::Mat gray; // convert the image to gray and put the result in gray mat
cv::cvtColor(img, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY); // img -> gray
// threshold the gray image to remove the noise and put the result again in gray image
// it will convert all the background to black and all the text and fields to white
cv::threshold(gray, gray, 150, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

// now enlage the text or the inpout text fields
cv::dilate(gray, gray, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(15, 3)));
// now clean the image, remove unwanted small pixels
cv::erode(gray, gray, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3)));

// find all non zero to get the max y
cv::Mat idx; // the findNonZero() function will put the result in this mat
cv::findNonZero(gray, idx); // pass the mat idx to the function
// now iterate throgh the idx to find the max y
double maxY = 0; // this will keep the max y, init value is 0
for (int i=0; i<idx.rows; ++i) {
    cv::Point pnt = idx.at<cv::Point>(i);
    if (pnt.y > maxY) { // if this Y is greater than the last Y, copy it to the last Y
        maxY = pnt.y; // this
    }
}

// crop the none blank (upper) part
// NOTE: from this point you can also crop the blank part
// (0,0) means start form left-top, (gray.cols, int(maxY+5)) means 
// whidth the same as the original image, and the height is
// the maxY + 5, 5 here means let give some margin the cropped image
// if you don't want, then you can delete it.
cv::Mat submat = img(cv::Rect(0, 0, gray.cols, int(maxY+5)));
cv::imshow("result", submat);

cv::waitKey();
```

**And it is the result:**

[image]

Hope it helps!

**Update:** 
If you interest to all min, max of the (x, y), then search like this:

```
double maxX = 0, minX = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
double maxY = 0, minY = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
for (int i=0; i<idx.rows; ++i) {
    cv::Point pnt = idx.at<cv::Point>(i);
    if (pnt.x > maxX) {
        maxX = pnt.x;
    }
    if (pnt.x < minX) {
        minX = pnt.x;
    }
    if (pnt.y > maxY) {
        maxY = pnt.y;
    }
    if (pnt.y < minY) {
        minY = pnt.y;
    }
}
```

So then you can crop anywhere of the image once you have these points.

Comment: This is (partly), what I suggested. Nevertheless, since you're only searching for `maxY`, the output of your solution for images, where the interesting part is at the bottom, won't be as desired by the question author as you always start at `(0, 0)`.

Comment: @HansHirse Answer updated. I have already done the most important part of the algorithm, the rest you can do by yourself.

Comment: @KaranKanwal Most part of the code is very clear, it just uses the OpenCV API. cv:: is the namespace in C++, in Python, you can use cv. instead. And `double` is data type which in Python you no need to declare the type. I cannot write code in Python, but you can just consider the steps I have implemented the Algorithm, and convert it to Python Or you can let some of your friends about the C++ code to convert it to Python. This script already does what you want in your question.

Comment: ok sure, I will try this. right now I am just writing the code by looking at your code.

Comment: @KaranKanwal If you are familiar with OpenCV API, then you can easily guess what I wrote in C++, at the most part it does not belong to the language used but belongs to the steps implemented. So do not be confused with C++ code above. Good Luck!

Comment: Can you explain this code a little bit.. like you have used grey but didn't give it any value, if I do this in python it will give me an error that grey is not defined.

Comment: @KaranKanwal Yes, I did not give any value, because I have passed the reference of the gray to the OpenCV function, so the function will put the result in that gray Mat. I will update the answer and later check again, I will my best to clear it more for you.

Comment: @KaranKanwal You are welcome! Now you can check again the answer, I did my best to clear it for you, then you can implement it in Python, now it can be very easy for you to convert the code to Python. Good Luck!